# What is the number of the solution of the following equation a+b+c+d+e = 18?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of integral solutions to the following equation? 
$$
a+b+c+d+e = 18
$$

Here, $a,b,c,d,e$ all are variables and can take zero and positive integers values. That means $a,b,c,d,e$ are all positive integers and can take zero values .

Comment: You mean the number of solutions?

Comment: This is a standard stars-and-bars problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: According to the information given, there is.

Comment: If a,b,c,d,e > 0 the the number of solution is (17 C 4 ) = 2380 .

Comment: @Waytoinfinity See pg 8 of http://www.math.cmu.edu/~mlavrov/arml/12-13/combinatorics-10-21-12.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume first that your numbers are positive (non-zero) integers; there is a combinatorial theorem that gives the solution to this problem:

> For any pair of positive integers $n$ and $k$, the number of distinct $k$-tuples of positive integers whose sum is $n$ is given by $n-1 \choose k-1$.

This is true since, as user *Gamma Function* suggests in a comment, if we take your sum $18$ to be $18$ stars

> $$\star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star \star$$

there will be $17$ gaps in them in which you can put $4$ bars to divide the stars in $5$ subsets, namely your $5$ integers

> $$\star \star | \star \star \star | \star \star \star \star \star | \star \star \star \star \star \star \star | \star$$

In how many different ways you can do this? Well, the same numbers of ways you would do choosing a $4$-element subset from a $17$-element set.
That is, $17 \choose 4$ $= 2380$; generally speaking, this is $n-1 \choose k-1$.

Supposing now that your integers can be $0$, you can bring back the problem to the one discussed above, by just manipulating your equation:

$$(a+1) + (b+1) + (c+1) + (d+1) + (e+1) = (18+1+1+1+1+1)$$

that is to say,

$$a' + b' + c' + d' + e' = 23$$

Now the problem is identical to the first one: in particular, the number of integers $k$ remains the same, while $n$ becomes $n+k$. Therefore, the number of integer solutions to your equation is exactly $18+5-1=22 \choose 4$ $= 7315$; generally speaking, this is $n+k-1 \choose k-1$: in fact, it's as if in the star drawing you're assuming that the object in whose gaps are to place bars are both stars and bars, so they are $n+k$ instead of just $n$.